# Handling complex data dependencies in parallel computation in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm looking to run several similar sparsely-related jobs in parallel using `parallel` package in R.
The nature of the jobs is that some of them are dependant upon others where dependency is an acyclic directed graph (not a tree). Also each individual job performance can vary in time from run to run.

I would like to `clusterApplyLB` to load-balance the jobs between work nodes because of varying execution time and I can't determine optimal sequence of jobs beforehand due to the same reason.

Hence, given list of jobs `{1,2,3,..}` and adjacency matrix `M`:
I'd like to throw job `i` into the 'pool' as soon as all of its dependencies `M[i]` have confirmed to master their successful completion.

Is it even possible, to build up work pool on the fly using `parallel`? If yes, how can I achieve that?